# How to dynamically handle commands in a chat program?

Tags: java, server, command, client, chat

My question is more of a design issue than anything else. I'm currently developing a classic Server-Client chat program in Java. Everything is fine until I get to the commands. I thought it would be convenient for users to send commands that would then be treated by the server for changing their nickname for example. The thing is I want to make flexible code and above all, object-oriented code. To avoid endless if/else if statements to know what command was typed I believe it would be better to create a class for each command which inherit from a superclass Command. Then I could return the specific command through a getCommand() function overriden in all subclasses. But it does not solve my problem at all. The server still needs to test with instanceof what command has been returned. One way to do it dynamically would be to sort of auto downcasting it from the superclass Command and then call the appropriate function in the server class. For example:

```
public void processCommand(CommandNick c) {}
public void processCommand(CommandKick c) {}
```

But I haven't found any proper way of doing that and even if I did, I feel like there's still a design issue here. And I am convinced there is a nice and flexible way to do it but days weren't enough for me to figure it out. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you please show some code snippets of your intial idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your server receives the message as an Object with a Sender and a String. Create your Command classes, and in the server init code, make a `HashMap<String, AbstractCommand>` with a `String` as key and your `AbstractCommand` class as value. Your commands should extend this class. Register all your commands, like so:

```
commandRegistry.put("help", new HelpCommandHandler());
```

I assume a command is a message with a `!` before it. So when you receive a message, check if it is a command:

```
Message message = (Your Message)
String messageBody = message.getBody();
Sender messageSender = message.getSender();

if(messageBody.startsWith("!")) {
    // Split the message after every space
    String[] commandParts = messageBody.split(" ");
    // The first element is the command base, like: !help
    String baseCommand = commandParts[0];
    // Remove the first character from the base, turns !help into help
    baseCommand = baseCommand.substring(1, baseCommand.length());
    // Creates a new array for the arguments. The length is smaller, because we won't copy the command base
    String[] args = new String[commandParts.length - 1];
    // Copy the elements of the commandParts array from index 1 into args from index 0
    if(args.length > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(commandParts, 1, args, 0, commandParts.length - 1);
    }
    // Your parse method
    processCommand(sender, baseCommand, args);
}

public void processCommand(Sender sender, String base, String[] args) {
    if(commandRegistry.containsKey(base)) {
        commandRegistry.get(base).execute(sender, args);
    } else {
        // Handle unknown command
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractCommand {
    public abstract void execute(Sender sender, String[] args);
}
```

Sample implementation. I assume your server is a Singleton, and you can get on Object of it with `Server.get()` or any similar method.

```
public class HelpCommandHandler extends AbstractCommand { /* !help */
    @Override
    public void execute(Sender sender, String[] args) {
        sender.sendMessage("You asked for help."); // Your code might not work like this.
    }
}

public class ChangeNickCommandHandler extends AbstractCommand { /* !changenick newNick */
    @Override
    public void execute(Sender sender, String[] args) {
        // I assume you have a List with connected players in your Server class
        String username = sender.getUsername(); // Your code might not work like this
        Server server = Server.get(); // Get Server instance
        server.getUsers().get(username).setNickname(args[0]); // Argument 0. Check if it even exists.
    }
}

// Server class. If it isn't singleton, you can make it one like this:
public class Server {
    private static Server self;
    public static Server init(/* Your args you'd use in a constructor */) { self = new Server(); return get(); }
    public static Server get() { return self; }

    private List<User> users = new List<User>();
    private HashMap<String, AbstractCommand> commandRegitry = new HashMap<>();

    // Make construcor private, use init() instead.
    private Server() {
        commandRegistry.put("help", new HelpCommandHandler());
        commandRegistry.put("changenick", new ChangeNickCommandHandler());
    }

    // Getters
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public HashMap<String, AbstractCommand> getRegistry() {
        return commandRegistry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem with your approach is that the handleCommand() function is implemented in the AbstractCommand class while I want the commands to be treated by the server itself. For example the usernames are stored by the server. So if a user wants to change their nickname, the command needs to call a method from the server..

Comment: I probably named it confusing. The if statement handles the command, by checking if it starts with a !. You should put that where you receive a message from a client. I'll rename the abstract method to something more clear.

Comment: In this case, I would have 2 channels open to the server. one that handles the normal chat stuff, and one that can process server side stuff behind the scenes.

Comment: @Brianbcr666Ray Why exactly? The server handles command stuff, by checking if it starts with a !, if it does process it, else handle in like a normal message.

Comment: @LórántViktorGerber I got what your code does and it's pretty close to what I'm expecting except that execute() is in the AbstractCommand class not in the server class. So it won't be able to apply changes to the server.

Comment: @RobinDosAnjos Added sample implementation

Comment: Thanks! I have a last question because this is only the server side. But in actuality, both server and client will receive commands. For example when a user changes their nickname, the server handles it with your approach. But then the server will warn everyone that somebody has renamed themselves by sending back a nick command that will then be interpreted by the client as a message. Should I make two classes? One for the server and one for the client even though they're strongly related or should the design be different? In any case thank you very much again I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @RobinDosAnjos I don't know what method you use to send information to the Client. If you use TCP packets, set a packet notifying the users of the nickname change. If you're just sending strings, the code works for a Client as well. If they are in the same program (Server and Client) make a separate class to make it look cleaner. But you should separate your Client and Server code

Comment: Yeah I think I'll just do the same thing on both sides. And I'll make classes for the server-sided commands and other classes for the client-sided ones! Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: @RobinDosAnjos Happy coding!

Comment: Instead of exposing server details through public getters you could also use inner classes or alternatively pass an interface from server to command's execute method as a third argument which would allow for performing particular actions on the server object. But the provided sample code is a good start and you should refine it to fit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of pseudo code to illustrate that your controller doesn't need to know about the command processors (no need for instanceof).

```
abstract class CommandProcessor {
    /* return boolean if this Command processed the request */  
    public static boolean processCommand(String command, User user, Properties chatProperties, Chat chat);
}

/* Handle anything */
public class CommandRemainder extends CommandProcessor {
    @Override
    public static boolean processCommand(String command, User user, Properties chatProperties, Chat chat) {
        chat.appendText("[" + user.getName() + "] " + command);
        return true;
    }
}

/* Handle color changing */
public class CommandColorizer extends CommandProcessor {
    protected static List<String> ALLOWED_COLORS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "green"));
    @Override
    public static boolean processCommand(String command, User user, Properties chatProperties, Chat chat) {
        if ("fg:".equals(command.trim().substring(0,3)) {
            String color = command.trim().substring(3).trim();
            if (ALLOWED_COLORS.contains(color)) {
                chat.setForeground(color);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class ChatController {
    protected Chat chat = new Chat();
    protected User user = getUser();
    protected Properties chatProperties = getChatProperties();
    protected List<CommandProcessor> commandProcessors = getCommandProcessors();

    {
        chat.addChatListener(new ChatListener(){
            @Override
            public void userChatted(String userChatString) {
                for (CommandProcessor processor : commandProcessors) {
                    if (processor.processCommand(userChatString, user, chatProperties, chat)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    List<CommandProcessor> getCommandProcessors() {
        List<CommandProcessor> commandProcessors = new ArrayList<>();

        commandProcessors.add(new CommandColorizer());
        commandProcessors.add(new CommandRemainder()); // needs to be last

        return commandProcessors;
    }
}
```